# save selected values from multiple select boxes into array

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-form

i have many select boxes on the page, which are genereted by js.

```
<select class='form-control mySelector' name='crossStageForm.teamIds[i]'>"
    <option value='${null}'>choose team</option>
    <c:forEach items='${crossStageForm.teamTOs}' var='teamTO'>
        <option value='${teamTO.id}' label='${teamTO.title}'/>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

i need to save ids into array of Long values of spring form. 
this is my form with array

```
public class CrossStageForm {
    //other fields
    private Long[] teamIds;
    //getters and setters 
}
```

also i think maybe in js i should generate also  constructions for saving i value and then using it as index for array, but anyway i'm not sure if i'm using right way for saving values from select to array . So the question is about many select boxes and saving it's values to array

Answer (score 0):

ok i found my mistake: select is on the form , so in select "name" attribute i shouldn't write form name, just "teamIds" and without index, now it works fine